# Hint system to tell a random false selection

Tags: c#

I'm making a c# windows form application in which there are five buttons each corresponding to a number 1-5 and the user guesses a random number out of those. I need to implement a hint which would tell the user a random false selection. How would I do this?

```
public partial class frmGuessANumber : Form
{
    int number;

    public frmGuessANumber()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        number = rnd.Next(1, 6);
    }

    private void SelectionMade(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button selection = (Button)sender;
        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(selection.Text);

        if (guess == number)
        {
            DisableButtons();

            lblMessage.Text = "Congratulations! " + guess + " is correct!";
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DisableButtons();

            lblMessage.Text = "Sorry! " + guess + " isn't the right answer.";
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void lblHint_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int wrongSelection = rnd.Next(2, 6);

        if (number == 1)
            lblHint.Text = "The number is not " + wrongSelection;
        else
            lblHint.Text = "The number is not " + (number - 1);
    }

    private void DisableButtons()
    {
        btnGuess1.Enabled = false;
        btnGuess2.Enabled = false;
        btnGuess3.Enabled = false;
        btnGuess4.Enabled = false;
        btnGuess5.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just store the buttons in an array and just disable the button at the given hint-number?

Answer (score 0):

You could

1) enumerate the possible numbers  using [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx)

2) then take all except the correct solution (in your case `number`). You can use the [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method

3) then you would randomly pick a number from this set as a `hint`. You can use the [ElementAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int CorrectAnswer = rnd.Next(1, 6);

int hint = Enumerable.Range(1,6).Where(x=>x != CorrectAnswer ).ElementAt(rnd.Next(1,5));
```

Since the user has been deleted, I will just leave the answer for future people with a similar problem:

Comment: I hope you realize that any chance of this getting accepted is now slim as the OPs account has been deleted

Comment: @Nkosi I just realised that :D this never happend to me before :D How funny